# Rule of thumb about when to use a temp object to hold reference to an object, rather than referering the whole path at every use?

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, unity-game-engine

I guess this question is for a large part a matter of what you prefer aswell as being very situational, but I just came across a path to a `gameobject` today with a pretty long reference, and I thought if a temp reference wouldn't be better for this situation.

The code:

```
if (enlargeableButtons[i][j].gameObject.activeSelf && enlargeableButtons[i][j].IsHighlighted())
{
    enlargeableButtons[i][j].gameObject.SetIsHighlighted(true, HoverEffect.EnlargeImage);
}
```

In a case where the path is this long with multiple array indexes to check, it would definitely be faster, but because of the extra object also be more expensive to do it like this:

```
GameObject temp = enlargeableButtons[i][j].gameObject;

if (temp.activeSelf && temp.IsHighlighted())
{
    temp.SetIsHighlighted(true, HoverEffect.EnlargeImage);
}
```

But how much and would it be worth it?

Comment: This looks like a prime example for premature optimization.

Comment: It's not a temp *object*, it's a temp *variable*. Variables in C# contain either structs (value types) or *references* (or, more rarely, pointers). A single object can have multiple references and references themselves are quite small.

Comment: This looks like a candidate for compile time optimization. Can anyone verify if C# will handle this when there is an array reference?

Comment: This is only good for readability to reduce the length of line of the code. That's it. You won't notice any performance gain unless you are calling Unity API that searches for GameObjects such as `GameObject.Find()`.

Answer (score 4):

I seriously doubt you will see any performance gain using a direct reference instead of going through the jagged array.
Maybe if this code is running in a very tight loop with lots and lots of iterations, you might get a few milliseconds of difference.

However, from the readability point of view, the second option is much more readable - so I would definitely go with it.

As a rule - **You should design your code for clarity, not for performance.**
Write code that conveys the algorithm it is implementing in the clearest way possible.
Set performance goals and measure your code's performance against them.
If your code doesn't measure to your performance goals, Find the bottle necks and treat them.
Don't go wasting your time on nano-optimizations when you design the code.

and a personal story to illustrate what I mean:
I once wrote a project where I had a lot of `obj.child.grandchild` calls. after starting to write the project I've realized it's going to be so many calls I just created a property on the class I was working on referring to that grandchild and my code suddenly became much nicer.

Answer (score 3):

Declaring `GameObject temp` just creates a reference to `enlargeableButtons[i][j].gameObject`. It is extra overhead, but not much. You won't notice a difference unless you're repeating that thousands of times or more.

As a personal rule, if I just need to reference it once, I don't bother with declaring a variable for it. But if I need to use something like `enlargeableButtons[i][j].gameObject` multiple times, then I declare a variable.

Comment: I updated my wording to clarify.

Comment: The cost of having an additional local variable is merely that the stack frame is incremented by an additional word when the frame is being set up.  That doesn't actually have any cost at all, unless it results in a stackoverflowexception, which is not actually a real concern.